# Why can't I get my javascript to show / hide additional type

Tags: javascript, css, coldfusion

It's me again... the self-taught, hobby-coder looking for help from the pros.

I'm pretty JS illiterate so, years ago, I had someone write a script for me to display / hide a form based on input. My brother teaches courses... some of them require a permit. To show the rest of the form for permit required courses, the user must select "Yes."

I'm adding another course type (npt_story_type) to the script, but it's not working (the others ARE.)

Here's the original script:

```
    // JavaScript Document

    


$( document ).ready( function () {
 
  $.validator.setDefaults( {
        submitHandler: function () {             
            return true;                 
          }          
    } ); 

        console.log("ready");
        var npType=$("#npt_story_type").val();
         console.log(npType);
        if(npType != 18 && npType != 59){
             
            $("#displayForm").css("display","block");
        }else{
             
            $("#displayForm").css("display","none");
        }
         
        
        $('input:radio[name="Permit"]').change(
        function(){
             
           if (npType == 18 && $(this).val() == 1) {  
           // open up rest of form
                $("#displayForm").css("display","block");
                  
          }
          else {
              if (  npType == 18 && $(this).val() == 0) {
                  $("#displayForm").css("display","none");
              }                       
          } 
          //tpe 
          if (npType == 59 && $(this).val() == 1) {  
           // open up rest of form
                $("#displayForm").css("display","block");
                  
          }
          else {
              if (  npType == 59 && $(this).val() == 0) {
                  $("#displayForm").css("display","none");
              }                       
          } 
  });

    
        //form validation
        $( "#registrationForm" ).validate( {
            ignore: ".ignore",
            rules: {
                coursedate: "required",
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",   
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                consent_0: "required",
                address: "required",
                city: "required",
                state: "required",
                zip: "required",
                phone: "required",
                legal: {
                     required: true,
                      min: 1
                },
                age21: {
                     required: true,
                      min: 1
                },
                hiddenRecaptcha: {
                 required: function () {
                        if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                            console.log('valid');
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            console.log('invalid');
                            return false;
                    }
                    }
                },
            },
            messages: {
                coursedate: "Select a course date",
                firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",                                                          
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                consent_0: "Please consent to our policy",
                address: "Please enter an address",
                city: "Please enter a city",
                state: "Please select a state",
                zip: "Please enter a zip",
                phone: "Please enter your phone number",
                legal: "You Must be a U.S. Legal Resident to register!" ,
                age21: "You Must agree to register!"
                
            },
            errorElement: "em",
            errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
                // Add the `invalid-feedback` class to the error element
                error.addClass( "invalid-feedback" );

                if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
                    error.insertAfter( element.next( "label" ) );
                }else if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "radio" ) 
                   {
                     error.insertAfter( element.next( "label" ) );
        
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter( element );
                }
            },
            highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                $( element ).addClass( "is-invalid" ).removeClass( "is-valid" );
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $( element ).addClass( "is-valid" ).removeClass( "is-invalid" );
            }
        } );

    } );
    function recaptchaCallback() {
          $('#hiddenRecaptcha').valid();
        };
```

Here's the updated code with npt_story_type "62" added:

```
    // JavaScript Document

    


$( document ).ready( function () {
 
  $.validator.setDefaults( {
        submitHandler: function () {             
            return true;                 
          }          
    } ); 

        console.log("ready");
        var npType=$("#npt_story_type").val();
         console.log(npType);
        if(npType != 18 && npType != 59 && npType != 62){
             
            $("#displayForm").css("display","block");
        }else{
             
            $("#displayForm").css("display","none");
        }
         
        
        $('input:radio[name="Permit"]').change(
        function(){
             
           if (npType == 18 && $(this).val() == 1) {  
           // open up rest of form
                $("#displayForm").css("display","block");
                  
          }
          else {
              if (  npType == 18 && $(this).val() == 0) {
                  $("#displayForm").css("display","none");
              }                       
          } 
          //tpe 
          if (npType == 59 && $(this).val() == 1) {  
           // open up rest of form
                $("#displayForm").css("display","block");
                  
          }
          else {
              if (  npType == 59 && $(this).val() == 0) {
                  $("#displayForm").css("display","none");
              }                       
          } 
          //tpe 
          if (npType == 62 && $(this).val() == 1) {  
           // open up rest of form
                $("#displayForm").css("display","block");
                  
          }
          else {
              if (  npType == 62 && $(this).val() == 0) {
                  $("#displayForm").css("display","none");
              }                       
          } 
  });

    
        //form validation
        $( "#registrationForm" ).validate( {
            ignore: ".ignore",
            rules: {
                coursedate: "required",
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",   
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                consent_0: "required",
                address: "required",
                city: "required",
                state: "required",
                zip: "required",
                phone: "required",
                legal: {
                     required: true,
                      min: 1
                },
                age21: {
                     required: true,
                      min: 1
                },
                hiddenRecaptcha: {
                 required: function () {
                        if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                            console.log('valid');
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            console.log('invalid');
                            return false;
                    }
                    }
                },
            },
            messages: {
                coursedate: "Select a course date",
                firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",                                                          
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                consent_0: "Please consent to our policy",
                address: "Please enter an address",
                city: "Please enter a city",
                state: "Please select a state",
                zip: "Please enter a zip",
                phone: "Please enter your phone number",
                legal: "You Must be a U.S. Legal Resident to register!" ,
                age21: "You Must agree to register!"
                
            },
            errorElement: "em",
            errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
                // Add the `invalid-feedback` class to the error element
                error.addClass( "invalid-feedback" );

                if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
                    error.insertAfter( element.next( "label" ) );
                }else if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "radio" ) 
                   {
                     error.insertAfter( element.next( "label" ) );
        
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter( element );
                }
            },
            highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                $( element ).addClass( "is-invalid" ).removeClass( "is-valid" );
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $( element ).addClass( "is-valid" ).removeClass( "is-invalid" );
            }
        } );

    } );
    function recaptchaCallback() {
          $('#hiddenRecaptcha').valid();
        };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about it isn't working? Is it giving an error message in the console?

Comment: No error. The other types work fine as well.

Comment: Found the problem... I assumed it was on the JS as I'm pretty illiterate when it comes to that. In fact, it was the code on the page itself. SMH Thanks much for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on the page code, not on the JS.
I guess trapping for the npt_story_type there would be wise. SMH

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).